# Angular2 http get first element

Tags: angular, http, get, observable, subscribe

I'd like to get just the value of "id" element from this JSON file:

```
{
"data": {
    "id": 2,
    "first_name": "lucille",
    "last_name": "bluth",
    "avatar": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/josephstein/128.jpg"
}
```

}

This is my code to fetch the data:

```
getData() {

    return this.http.get('https://reqres.in/api/users/2')
    .map((respone: Response) => respone.json());
}
```

How can I get just the 'id' value?

Comment: are you returning an observable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using RxJs, after you call `getData()`, you must subscribe to the result, and then parse the data.

i.e.

```
this.getData().subscribe(result => {

    // handle the response

    return result.data.id;

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are returning an Observable from your service,
You can use variety of RxJs first operator

```
this.serviceName.getData().first(x => console.log(x.id)) //logs the first id
                          .subscribe(data => console.log(data); // logs the stream of data
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do something like:

```
getData() {
    return this.http.get('https://reqres.in/api/users/2')
                    .map((respone: Response) => respone.json().data.id);
}
```

Will return only the id field from response instead of the entire data object.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this in your component's HTML where you're displaying the data.
For example:

```
<div *ngFor = 'let first of http'>
    {{first.id}}
</div>
```